# Proof of $\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x| f(t)|dt$ exists $\implies$ $ \lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f(t)dt$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b[\to \mathbb R$ continuous and integrable on $[a,b[$. I want to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x |f(t)|dt$ exists $\implies$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f(t)dt$ exists. I set $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$ In my course they proved that $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b[$ and thus $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$ exist.

Can I do as follow : I set $f^+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f^{-}(x)=-\min\{f(x),0\}$. Since $f^{+}$ and $f^-$ are continuous  $$0\leq  f^+\leq |f|\quad \text{and}\quad 0\leq f^-\leq |f|,$$
and $\int_a^b |f|$ exists, we have that $$\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f^+\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f^-$$
exists. Therefore, $$\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f=\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f^+-\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x f^-,$$
and thus it exists.

Does it work ?

Comment: "... and $\int_{a}^{b}|f|$ exists". Not given. It would have to be proven, and it is false for some types of integrals.

Comment: @cactus : Could you explain ? $\int_a^b|f|$ exist by hypothesis. I denote $F^\pm(x)=\int_a^x f^\pm$. We have that $F^\pm$ are increasing and upper-bounded. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to x }F^\pm(x)$ exist, no ?

Comment: For me it works...

Comment: It is nowhere written in the hypotheses. If $\int$ is Riemann integral, or even Henstock integral, it is not true that if $f$ in continuous and integrable on $[a,b[$ then $\int_{a}^{b}|f|$ exists. For Lebesgue integral it does follow.

Comment: @cactus: What do you mean ? $\int_a^b|f|$ is by definition $\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x |f|$ (as suggested by the OP). It's indeed more commonly written as $\int_a^{b-}|f|$ but we often see in the literature $\int_a^b|f|$ do denote $\int_a^{b-}|f|$ if there is no confusion...

Comment: What would be $\int_a^b|f|$ for a function that is integrable on $[a,b[$ if it's not $\lim_{x\to b}\int_a^x |f|$ ?

Comment: @Peter: Normally, $\int_a^b |f|$ make sense only if $f$ is piecewise continuous (for Riemann integral) and thus, suggest that $\lim_{x\to b^-}f$ exist. For example : the notation $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is not totally correct if $\int$ denote the Riemann integral. But in Lebesgue sense, it works, and moreover, we have that $$\lim_{x\to 1}\int^{R}_{[0,x]} \frac{1}{\sqrt t}dt=\int_{[a,b]}^L\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$$ where $\int^R$ is for Riemann integral and $\int^L$ is for Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Surb The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\right)$ is continuous and Henstock integrable on $[0,1[$. However, $\int_{0}^{1}|f|$ doesn't exist. Therefore, the type of integral must be specified, and the existence of $\int_{a}^{b}|f|$ must be justified for that particular definition of integral.

Comment: @Surb Now I noticed that he wants to prove an implication, and not that $\lim_{t\to b}\int_{a}^{t}|f|$ exists. There is a missing "if" there.

Comment: @cactus: I don't know Henstock integral. Sorry. Indeed, $\int_a^b |f|$ makes sense for piecewise continuous functions only. Nevertheless, when there is no ambiguity (and as I mentioned in a previous post), $\int_a^b|f|$ is often used in the literature to specified $\int_a^{b-}|f|$ ([see for example wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) ). I think here it was clear (at least for me), but indeed, the OP could have mentioned it.

Answer (score -2):

It is enough to show that for every Cauchy sequence $x_n$, $\int_{a}^{x_n}f(t)dt$ is a Cauchy sequence. This results from the fact that $|\int_{x_n}^{x_m}f(t)dt|\leq \int_{x_n}^{x_m}|f(t)|dt$.

Comment: I downvoted because it doesn't answer to my question. Moreover it's more or less the same thing as proving that $x\longmapsto \int_a^x f(t)dt$ is uniformly continuous, since to prove that $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$ exist, it's exactly showing that $(F(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence when $x_n\to b$...